# Why error block is not returning from customRequest file in axios in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios, try-catch

I am facing the following issue, please correct me where I am going wrong:

Here is my code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-wave-o1z8q

Here if you check then in the App.JS file I am calling `getSync()` with URL argument. And `getSync()` is Axios get a call within the `try and catch block`.

**What Output I am getting:**: I am not getting a proper error message in a proper block of code catch and then()

**My observation:** If I am implementing try and catch with as it is in App.js and call API directly in `getUser()` then it reflects properly error in the catch block.

However, when implementing same with return from another file it giving this issue

**My Objective**: My objective is that if we get any error from API then it should return from the catch block of `getSync()` in `customRequest.js` and then `2nd then() of getUser in App.js`

I know I am missing some piece of code here, please guide me

Comment: Don't `catch` in `getSync`, use `.catch()` in `getUser`, or if you prefer use `try/catch` with `await getSync` in `getUser`

Comment: you aren't catching in `getUser`, use the `.catch` method to capture that error. If you need to do something specific with the customRequest, you can use a try catch, but make sure you throw the error again in your catch so the next catch can handle it. However you should adjust how you are calling this api method and use state in react to render the error

Comment: I will be grateful if you can help me with the sandbox code example :)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-http-w12tj

Comment: Thanks, everyone also @JohnRuddell, it worked. I also like to mention that I had used `return err` in `getSync()` instead of `throw err` (this was also missed in the original code.).

Comment: I changed it to `throw err` so that the `.catch` would also pick up this error. If you look at the codesandbox now you'll see I put the error message in react state in the component. so you can see a working example of how to get the view to present the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working now as per expectation.
[codesandbox.io/s/blissful-http-w12tj](http://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-http-w12tj) –
By @John Ruddell